# How to implement a union type as an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like an interface that describes a dependency between two object properties - the object should have a `region` only when it has a `country`.

So far I have tried doing this using a union type between two interfaces:

```
interface CountryOnly {
    country?: string;
}

interface CountryAndRegion extends CountryOnly {
    country: string;
    regiong?: string;
}

export type Geo = CountryOnly | CountryAndRegion;
```

However, when I try to state that a class implements this union, I receive an error:

```
export class ClientResponse implements Geo {
    alias: string;
    country: string | null;
    region: string | null;
}
```

> A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.

What's the appropriate thing to do here?  I am currently casting with `as Geo` for lack of a better idea, but that seems far from ideal.

Comment: You can't, `interface`s can't be unions by definition

Comment: You need generic instead

Answer (score 0):

```
export class ClientResponse<T extends 'CountryOnly' | 'CountryAndRegion' = 'CountryOnly'> {
    alias!: string;
    country!: T extends 'CountryAndRegion' ? string : string | null;
    regiong!: T extends 'CountryAndRegion' ? string | null : never;
    // ! s so not errors on not assigned
}
```

Not pretty, but looks like this